# SELinux preventing Apache from writing to a file

Tags: centos, redhat, apache-2.4, selinux, centos7

SELinux is preventing the `apache` user from writing to a log file which it owns. When I do `setenforce 0` it works. Otherwise it shows this error

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/www/webapp/k/site/k.log'
```

The security context of the file:

```
$ ll -Z k.log 
-rw-r--r--. apache apache system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 k.log
```

The file was created when the SELinux mode was set to permissive.

How to set the security context so the `apache` user can write in that directory? I did set that directory security context using `chcon` but I can't find a suitable file type.

From `audit.log`:

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1409945481.163:1561): avc:  denied  { append } for  pid=16862 comm="httpd" name="k.log" dev="dm-1" ino=201614333 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 tclass=file
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1409945481.163:1561): arch=c000003e syscall=2 success=no exit=-13 a0=7fa8080847a0 a1=441 a2=1b6 a3=3 items=0 ppid=15256 pid=16862 auid=4294967295 uid=48 gid=48 euid=48 suid=48 fsuid=48 egid=48 sgid=48 fsgid=48 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="httpd" exe="/usr/sbin/httpd" subj=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 key=(null)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For files you want Apache to be able to write to, the type must be set to `httpd_sys_rw_content_t`.

Comment: The correct context-type for Apache to write logs is `httpd_log_t`, not anything content related.

Answer (score 23):

As already stated, you should instruct SELINUX to allow writing to that file. The right thing to do is to mark `/var/www/webapp/k/site/` as of type `httpd_sys_rw_content_t`

To permanently mark that directory as `httpd_sys_rw_content_t`, you can use the command **`semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/www/webapp/k/site(/.*)?; restorecon -RF /var/www/webapp/k/site/`**
This will survive SELINUX binary policy updates and filesystem relabeling.

Comment: this should have been marked as the correct answer.  and it is advised to permanently mark the directory (as stated in this answer).

Comment: You probably need to escape the parentheses from the shell.

Answer (score 8):

This will change the permissions:

```
chcon --type httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/www/webapp/k/site/k.log
```

Comment: I get this error:

-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Answer (score 0):

@shodanshok's answer works except I had to remove the brackets out from mine and then everything worked...

```
semanage fcontext -a -t 
httpd_sys_rw_content_t 
/var/www/myfolder/.*?; restorecon -RF 
/var/www/myfolder
```